# Some alternating sum of integer part of $\frac{kb}{1722}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, summation, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For every integer $k$ coprime to 1722, how can one compute the sum

$\sigma(k)= \sum_{1\leq b\leq 1722, (1,b)=1722} \lfloor\frac{kb}{1722}\rfloor (-1)^{b-\lfloor \frac{b}{2}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{b}{3}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{b}{7}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{b}{41}\rfloor}$?

(Here the sum is taken over integers $b$ between $1$ and 1722 coprime to 1722.)

An approach would be to consider a linear function $\tau(k)$ and compute $\sigma(k)-\tau(k)$ where

\begin{align*}\tau(k) &= \sum_{1\leq b\leq 1722, (1,b)=1722} \frac{kb}{1722}(-1)^{b-\lfloor \frac{b}{2}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{b}{3}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{b}{7}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{b}{41}\rfloor}\\
&=\frac{k}{1722} \sum_{1\leq b\leq 1722, (1,b)=1722}b\cdot (-1)^{b-\lfloor \frac{b}{2}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{b}{3}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{b}{7}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{b}{41}\rfloor} = -\frac{80\cdot 1724k}{1722}
\end{align*}

It is not hard to see that $\sigma(k)-\tau(k)$ is bounded. I used Python to compute $\tau(k)$.

I would like to know how to compute both $\sigma(k)$ and $\tau(k)$ by hand.

Comment: Do you need an exact result? Do you need it only for 1722?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what is this for?

Comment: These are signatures of certain 8-dimensional manifolds. I would like to know an exact formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $\tau(k)$ to approximate $\sigma(k)$.

Your calculation of $\tau(k)$ was not correct. This is the correct function:
$$\frac{k}{1722} \sum _b b (-1)^{-\left\lfloor \frac{b}{2}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{b}{3}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{b}{7}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{b}{41}\right\rfloor +b}=-\frac{68960}{861}k$$

And this is a table to show how good is the approximation
$$
\begin{array}{r|r|r}
k & \sigma(k) & \tau(k)\\
\hline
 100 & -8008 & -8009.29 \\
 200 & -16016 & -16018.6 \\
 300 & -24032 & -24027.9 \\
 400 & -32036 & -32037.2 \\
 500 & -40044 & -40046.5 \\
 600 & -48060 & -48055.7 \\
 700 & -56052 & -56065. \\
 800 & -64076 & -64074.3 \\
 900 & -72088 & -72083.6 \\
 1000 & -80092 & -80092.9 \\
 2000 & -160184 & -160186. \\
 3000 & -240276 & -240279. \\
 4000 & -320372 & -320372. \\
 5000 & -400464 & -400465. \\
 6000 & -480548 & -480557. \\
 7000 & -560648 & -560650. \\
 8000 & -640744 & -640743. \\
 9000 & -720832 & -720836. \\
 10000 & -800928 & -800929. \\
\end{array}
$$